# Undefined property error when calling a library function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two controllers in user folder.
One is user and othe one is profile.
And also have a library called category_detail in category folder.
when I call 
`$this->category_detail->get_category_detail(2);` in user controller it works well.
But when I do same call in profile controller it gives an error.
In both file I have loaded category_detail library in constructor.
 error is follows.

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Profile::$category_detail

Filename: user/profile.php

Answer (score 0):

check this link

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

you have to put your library file in application/libraries folder

Comment: I have put it in library folder.